# Load multiple files in React-Native in one line

Tags: react-native

I have multiple files that I am currently loading like this:

```
import Header from './shared_components/header'
import NavBar from './shared_components/navbar'
```

And I want to load them in one line. Something like this:

```
import {Header, NavBar} from './shared_components/'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an `index.js` at the root of `shared_components`.

```
# /shared_components/index.js

import Header from './header';
import NavBar from './navbar';

export {
    Header,
    NavBar
};
```

Then use this in your file:

```
import {Header, NavBar} from './shared_components';
```

Answer (score 0):

Create main file named `index.js` at the root of `shared_components`.

```
shared_components/index.js

import Header from './header';
import NavBar from './navbar';

//Can also do this in `shared_components/index.js file` ...

const SimpleFunction = () => {
    //Your code
}

export {
    Header,
    NavBar,
    SimpleFunction
};
```

**Importing type 1**

```
import {Header, NavBar,SimpleFunction} from './shared_components';
```

**Importing type 2**

// You can replace your name with Helper

```
import * as Helper from './shared_components';
```

**Usage type 1**

**If your imported component return JSX then**

```
<Header/> || <Header></Header>
```

**If your imported component is not return JSX then**

```
const value = SimpleFunction()
```

**Usage type 2**

**If your imported component return JSX then**

```
<Helper.Header/> || <Helper.Header></Helper.Header>
```

**If your imported component is not return JSX then**

```
const value = Helper.SimpleFunction()
```

Hope this helps ;)